# What's the pros and cons of ForeignKey instead of ManyToManyField

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, many-to-many

In django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models) it's modeled a poll structure:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

but I always wonder why they don't implement like ManyToMany relation:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: They're completely different things, foreign key is a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yes I know. But why they choose ForeignKey? A Question has many Choices and the same Choice could be used in many Questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure they used a ForeignKey (One To Many) relationship in the tutorial because they were trying to keep the example as simple as possible, with only two models: `Question` and `Choice`. Notice that `votes` is a field of the `Choice` model, which makes it very simple to show the results of the poll.

If you were doing a poll where you had the same choices for every question (Strongly Agree, Somewhat Agree, etc.), then a ManyToMany relationship might be appropriate. But that makes things more complicated. Your proposed models for a ManyToMany relationship were:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

But this wouldn't work correctly without some changes.`votes` is still a field of the `Choice` table, but now each choice applies to many questions. You would be able to see that the Strongly Agree choice got 38 votes, but you couldn't tell which questions the voters agreed with. To be able to tabulate the votes correctly, you would have to do something like

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    choices = models.ManyToManyField('Choice', through='QuestionChoices')

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class QuestionChoices(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now you can tabulate exactly how many people voted for each question-choice combination, but it's more complicated and not very suitable for a getting-started tutorial.

With the ManyToMany models that you proposed, Django would automatically create the `QuestionChoices` model behind the scenes, but in order to attach the `votes` field to it you have to do it explicitly yourself.

If you have a relationship that could be modeled as either OneToMany or ManyToMany, the pros and cons depend on your particular application. In general you want to use a model that most accurately reflects the real-life situation. But you also have to consider how you need to update and summarize the data, and try to arrive at the best compromise. In my experience there aren't many situations where the choice is difficult.

Comment: thanks a lot. It's  a very detailed description about theory and practical issues